# Isi 2016 problem no. 7 integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$f$ is a differentiable  function such that $f(f(x))=x$ where $x \in [0,1]$.Also $f(0)=1$.Find the value of

$$\int_0^1(x-f(x))^{2016}dx$$